# Clarification: Can I use the fastlane snapshots without the Test target

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

Can I use the fastlane snapshots without the Test target?

I need to know the fastane snapshot setup needs to be added the test target. If the Test target is not available and If I add the fastlane snapshot, does it works for me or not?